# How do i Change a GameObject from another script to the GameObject the current script is on

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject

im trying to set the game object in script1 to be the game object script2 is on

```
public class Script1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameObject ObjectToMove;
}


public class Script2 : MonoBehaviour
{
   void Start()
   {
     Script1.ObjectToMove = this.gameObject;
   }
}
```

Comment: The code you wrote already works for static variables. For instance variables, you need a reference to the instance of the script you want to modify. Can you clarify what's going wrong when you try to use this in your project?

Comment: I agree with Gregory, a bit more info would make it easier to answer your question.For now the only thing I can say is: make sure both the component and the gameobject which Script2 is attached to are enabled, else the Start method won't be called.